# publish jax-ws service on public ip

Tags: web-services, ip, jax-ws, endpoint

I've a simple jax-ws web service that on localhost works fine with the clients, but now I want to publish the web service on a public ip, so the clients can interact with it through wan network instead lan network.
I signed to no-ip dns service provider and defined my host like "myname.no-ip.info".

In my code i start the service in this way:

```
Endpoint.publish("http://localhost:8080/baseStationProvider", new BaseStationProvider());
```

and the browser at http://myname.no-ip.info:8080/baseStationProvider@wsdl doesn't show the wsdl.

If i start the service in this way:

```
Endpoint.publish("http://myname.no-ip.info/baseStationProvider", new BaseStationProvider());
```

compiling the code, it raise this exception:
Server Runtime Error: java.net.SocketException: Unresolved address

Any idea to problem and/or how to do what i need?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems likely to do with routing and firewalls as opposed to web service publication etc.  Ignoring the web-service aspect, can you even reach your server when you use this in your browser:

```
http://myname.no-ip.info:8080/
```

?

Which should look the same as

```
http://localhost:8080/
```

If not, then it is probably DNS/Routing/Firewalls that you need to check.  Diagnostics that will help there are:
 1) can the machine you are testing on resolve the DNS name mynam.no-ip.info?  `nslookup`, ping, traceroute/tracert
 2) is there a firewall blocking port 8080 from reaching local host?  If the route from the internet to your host hits a firewall (which it will) that firewall will have to forward the request.

Good luck.

Comment: thanks, solved on another pc of another network. so it was a router/firewall/uac problem, the WS is ok.